# How do I configure reverse DNS for a 6to4 site?

Tags: domain-name-system, reverse-dns, ipv6

I'm using 6to4. How do I configure reverse DNS for my site? It's a Linux server, I'm using freedns.afraid.org and am not running bind.

Comment: Are you using Bind? Windows DNS? Another system? More information would be very helpful as the steps are different from one Operating System to the other.

Answer (score 4):

https://6to4.nro.net/, click '6to4 within 6to4 island', and follow the instructions. They will delegate rDNS of your 6to4 zone to your nameservers (ns1.afraid.org to ns5.afraid.org). From then on, you can use afraid.org's interface to set rDNS.